# What can I do about a gas pipe that is in my way?

Tags: plumbing, gas

I have just taken part of a studded wall out for modernization reasons, but found a gas pipe right there in the middle of the aperture. The easy way round this would be to use a 'flexi hose' is this ok to do so?

Comment: "flexi hose" is only for connecting appliances, it's not to be used anywhere else.

Answer (score 5):

As Tester101 mentioned, a flexible hose is not suitable for concealing in the wall.

Similar to plumbing that is in the way, the pipe needs to be re-routed and moved.  Depending on your location, this might be something that is permitted by the home owner or it might require a licensed technician to complete.

Unlike water where a small leak is unlikely to kill anyone, an incorrectly plumbed gas line can be deadly and as a result, unless you have experience working with gas lines, it is best and safest to call someone in to complete this for you.

Comment: I guess you missed the episode of mythbusters.  You have to fill up a house with a considerable amount of natural gas before it becomes flammable.  To the point where there is no possible way that you could stand the smell.  I am not saying don't follow code because it is very important to do it right the first time but gas is really only seriously dangerous when pressurized (hooked up to an appliance incorrectly).

Comment: Gas pipes are always pressurized.  Leaking gas is bad, big leak or small leak.

Comment: They have a very small amount of pressure.  Nobody saying that leaking gas is a good thing.  You are missing the point.  You act like if you have a gas leak your house will blow up.  It has been proven wrong and when do you hear of this happen?  The fact is you acted like it is deadly when more people in fact drown in their homes.

Comment: I didn't say your house would blow up anywhere in my answer, I just said it *can* be deadly.  I'm just providing all around safe advice - you seem to be missing this point. It's a cavalier attitude towards safety that gets a lot of people killed,

Comment: @tom many buildings have blown up due to gas leaks. Not saying it's a widespread problem, but it does happen.

Comment: propane leaks r really bad

Answer (score 1):

Most likely that's a copper or iron natural gas pipe.  Did that pipe feed a wall heater at some point?

You'll need a licensed gas fitter/plumber to re-route or remove it.

I wouldn't attempt to do that work yourself.  If you did and there was ever a problem (leak) or fire that was later traced back to any change you did, then you could be up for some insurance problems.

Comment: Agreed that I wouldn't attempt this myself, but whether or not you need to be licensed to do it depends on your region.  Good point about insurance too!